# Условия в одну строчку

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. Объясните пожалуйста, что означает и как работает данная запись на javascript?

```
  !$(this).is(".required:visible") || "" != o && r != l
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто идите (мысленно) по условиям и "выполняйте" их:

```
if( $(this).is(".required:visible") == false )
{
    return true;
}
if( o != "" && r != 1 )
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Если ничего не напутал :)

Answer (score 0):

*Приоритет и ассоциативность операторов* [на англ.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) объясняют, почему можно так упростить или расставить скобки:

```
A  ||  B  &&  C

// или
A  ||  ( B && C)

// т.е.
( !$(this).is(".required:visible"))  ||  (( "" != o)  &&  ( r != l))

// или
( 
    ( $(this).is(".required:visible") == false)
    ||
    (
        o != ""
        &&
        r != 1
    )
)
```

**Подробности**, не имеющие прямого отношения к вашему примеру.

1. *Проверка на короткое замыкание* (?) – то, что на английском называется [Short Circuit Evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) — при оценке логического выражения `(A && B)` если `A` уже вернуло  `false`, то нет смысла проверять ещё и `B`: так понятно, что результатом будет `false`. Если `B` не просто значение, а что-то вычисляемое, например, результат выполнения метода, то он запущен не будет. То же относится к выражению `(A || B)`: если `A` вернуло `true`, то не важно, что будет у `B`, и оно не проверяется / не выполняется.
2. Операторы `&&` и `||` возвращают [не обязательно `Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Summary): они возвращают значение того операнда, который определил значение оператора. Например, `("trololo" || false)` вернет строку `"trololo"`.